# Generic parameter with predefined method signature

Tags: c#, http, generics

I have a HTTP client helper to make post request to an API:

```cs
 public static T post(U request, string URL)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var responseContent = httpClient.PostAsync(
                    URL,
                    new StringContent(
                            JsonSerializer.Serialize<U>(
                                request,
                                Config.QrAuthJsonConfig.options
                            ),
                            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                            "Application/Json"
                    )
             ).Result;

            var response = responseContent.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(response);
        }
```

As you can note, URL is a second param. I would like a way **U request** can have a method signature to get the URL value from **U request** instance.

For example:

```cs
request.getUrl();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `.Result` on an `async` call, change to `public async static Task<T> post`, then remove `.Result` and `await` the call to  `PostAsync`, same with the following line, then use `await responseContent.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: What are `T` and `U`? Are you trying to use type parameters?

Comment: seems like you need a generic constraint, something like `public static T post(U request, string URL) where U: whatever`

Comment: You need to declare them as generic parameters `public static T post<U,T>(U request, string URL)`

Answer (score 0):

The (“post”) method with a “generic parameter with a predefined method” could use an interface or a (base) class.

**1. Using an interface:**

```
public static TSerialization Post<TSerialization, TRequest>(TRequest request) where TRequest : IUrlInfo
{
   //…
}
```

Define an interface

```
public interface IUrlInfo
{
    string Url { get; set; }
}
```

that you implement for each request

```
public class SomeRequest : IUrlInfo
{
    public string Url { get; set; } = “default-value-is-not-needed.com”;

    // other properties
}
```

**2. Using an abstract class:**

```
public static TSerialization Post<TSerialization, TRequest>(TRequest request) where TRequest : RequestBase
{
   //…
}
```

Define an abstract class

```
public abstract class RequestBase
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

that you implement for each request

```
public class SomeRequest : RequestBase
{
   // other properties
}
```